# Stop the Nav-slider from moving when selecting a slide in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js, react-slick

**Disable the sliding when selecting a slide in the slick slider**

When selecting one slide from the `nav-slider` thumb slide, I want it to become active without sliding to the left or to the center. Is there a way to achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mainSlider = $(".slider-for");
  var navSlider = $(".slider-nav");

  mainSlider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    prevArrow: ".prev-arrow",
    nextArrow: ".next-arrow",
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    fade: true,
    speed: 300,
    cssEase: "cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.18, 1)",
    asNavFor: ".slider-nav",
  });

  navSlider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: ".slider-for",
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    swipe: false, // Disable swiping for navigation slider
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 5,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 640,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 580,
        settings: {
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

I already tried this `$('.slider-nav .slick-slide').on('click', function (event) { $('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).data('slickIndex')); });`

Answer (score 0):

`slickGoTo` navigates to a slide by index. It does not disable autoplay.

To disable autoplay, you have to set `autoplay` to `false`:

```js
$('.slider-nav .slick-slide').on('click', () => {
  $('.slider-for').slick(
    'slickSetOption',
    {
      autoplay: false
    },
    false
  )
})
```